# How to run same queries on multiple databases in one go?

Tags: mysql, database

There are three databases for development, Testing and Live. I make change in development database and then sync this database with other two . Is there any option to run same queries on all the data base in one go ?

Comment: You can use trigger with same queries.

Comment: What are the queries? DML? DDL?

Answer (score 0):

You can just call one query on each database separated by semicolons and change database each time... something like this:

```
USE database_one;
SELECT * FROM table;

USE database_two;
SELECT * FROM table;

USE database_three;
SELECT * FROM table;
```

Comment: Actually there are many procedures that I updated. So how can I update all these in one go ?